# Protractor concatenate two spans with same class name

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm new to Protractor E2E Testing. On a webpage I'm testing, there are two span tags with a class name of `name-part`. I need a way to concatenate the values of both in an element result. Here is how the code is laid out.

```html
<div class="offer-name">
  1.01 ct. Center Diamond
  <span class="name-part">Monique Lhuillier Timeless Rollover Halo Diamond Engagement Ring</span>
  <span class="name-part">in 18k Rose Gold</span>
</div>
```

I need to concatenate both spans into one assertion. `Monique Lhuillier Timeless Rollover Halo Diamond Engagement Ring in 18k Rose Gold`

Here is my code:

```javascript
tester.it('Clicking the defined number of products should bring up Product Details page every time', (testContext) => {
catalogResults().totalResults().then((totalCount) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) {
    let testLink = element.all(by.css('.catalog-offer a')).get(i);
    const offerResultsName = element.all(by.css('.offer-name')).get(i).getText();
    const offerResultsPrice = element.all(by.css('.offer-details-wrapper .price-display')).get(i).getText();
    testerUtils.performActionAndWait(testLink.click);
    element(by.css('.image-and-details .name-start')).getText().then(displayName => {
      expect(offerResultsName).to.eventually.include(displayName, 'Display name does not match with results name.')
      console.log(displayName);
    })
    element(by.css('.details .subtotal > span')).getText().then(displayPrice => {
      expect(offerResultsPrice).to.eventually.equal(displayPrice, 'Display price does not match with results price.');
      console.log(displayPrice);
    });
    expect(testerUtils.getPageId()).to.eventually.equal('Recently Purchased Engagement Ring Details');
    testerUtils.go(testContext.url);
  }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work (may need some changes)

```
let elementsWithTheSameClass = element.all(by.css('.someClass'))

let arrayOfStrings = await elementsWithTheSameClass.getText() // ["Monique Lhuillier Timeless Rollover Halo Diamond Engagement Ring", "in 18k Rose Gold"]

let endResult = arrayOfStrings.join(" ") // "Monique Lhuillier Timeless Rollover Halo Diamond Engagement Ring in 18k Rose Gold"

expect(endResult).toBe("Monique Lhuillier Timeless Rollover Halo Diamond Engagement Ring in 18k Rose Gold")
```

Comment: Thanks much! I’ll give this a whirl. I’d totally forgotten about `join`.